# Как импортировать и использовать модель с анимацией из blender в Unity3D?

Tags: unity3d, blender

Проблема такая: заригал и анимировал лоуполи модель из интернетов для своего проектика в юньке. Экспортировал из блендера в fbx с такими настройками [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

это моделька с анимкой и ригами, также я экспортировал этуже модель без рига и анимки как обычную. Закинул модельки в юньку, без рига и анимки выставил как дефолтную модель персонажа
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И модель с анимкой, но в модели почемуто несколько анимаций хотя я делал только одну но думаю это не суть среди прочих анимаций в модели есть и та что сделал я и ее можно даже проиграть в инпекторе юньки без проблем
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но проблема заключается в том что если закинуть эту модель в аниматор то закидываются и прочие, что раздражает и я не понимаю откуда они там взялись. И если среди всех подключить именно мою то она просто не работает
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Мой орел остается статичным. Подскажите что я сделал не так? Пробовал поискать в интернетах но информации по экспорту модели с анимацией и ее импорту в аниматор я найти не смог.

Comment: Аниматор на модель я закинул и контроллер тоже указал

Comment: В смысле? А как модель будет двигаться без рига? Риг нужен и уже на него вешается анимация